# Why iOS Simulator show my app as I want and my iphone doesn't show anything?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiview

When I use the size classes with Xcode 6 and I run my app on iOS simulator, it seems to work as i want, but Xcode sends this message:

> 2014-10-19 17:34:05.269 One or Two[1260:169071] Unable to
>   simultaneously satisfy constraints.   Probably at least one of the
>   constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1)
>   look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
>   (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints
>   and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe230696400 V:[UIButton:0x7fe230691cd0'About']-(39)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fe2306946d0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe2306964a0 V:[UIButton:0x7fe230691cd0'About']-(51)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fe2306946d0]>"
```

> )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2014-10-19 17:34:05.271 One or
>   Two[1260:169071] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2014-10-19 17:34:05.272 One or
>   Two[1260:169071] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2014-10-19 17:34:05.285 One or
>   Two[1260:169071] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2014-10-19 17:34:05.286 One or
>   Two[1260:169071] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2014-10-19 17:34:05.287 One or
>   Two[1260:169071] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2014-10-19 17:34:05.288 One or
>   Two[1260:169071] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2014-10-19 17:34:05.288 One or
>   Two[1260:169071] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2014-10-19 17:34:05.289 One or
>   Two[1260:169071] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2014-10-19 17:34:05.290 One or
>   Two[1260:169071] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2014-10-19 17:34:05.291 One or
>   Two[1260:169071] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2014-10-19 17:34:05.291 One or
>   Two[1260:169071] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       ""
>   )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful.

And when I run the aplication on a real iPhone 5S or on an iPad Air, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Did you see you are posting nearle the same thing again and again, but the code which does describe the problem in detail is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how you're running the app.  I don't know if you're running on device in debug mode, but you should probably fix the autolayout constraints you have not defined properly in your app.  It appears you have constraints that conflict and you have not set priorities in them properly.

For example, you could have 2 constraints in one view where width = 50 and width = 60, and both have priority set to 1000.

For more information, please read through [Apple's Auto Layout Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)